# is it possible to add the fonts to system in macOS 13.3

Tags: fonts

I want to add the fonts to texlive system path in macOS 13.3, then I tried to move the fonts to path `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/zheyuye` like this:

```
mv ~/.fonts/* /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/zheyuye
```

then update the fonts like this:

```
> sudo mktexlsr
```

in the cls, I am setting the main fonts like this:

```
\setmainfont{HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman.otf}

\setCJKmainfont{Pro_GB18030.ttf}
```

when I compile, the texstudio still shows error could not found the font. Am I missing something? what should I do to add the fonts? I have already know that when I set the absolute path, this compile will work, but now I need to run the compile process both in macOS(develop environmnet) and Ubuntu(production environment). I need to use a common path so I did not need to change the path when I publish the tex compile engine to production.

Comment: The `fonts` directory needs to follow the TDS, so you need `.../fonts/opentype` to hold the OpenType fonts and `.../fonts/truetype` to hold the TrueType fonts. You can't have a generic folder `zheyuye`.